# Corda: Create and consume same state in one flow?

Tags: corda

is it possible to create and consume the same corda state in one flow or create and consume it in different subflows?
I get the following error: 
`Caused by: net.corda.core.flows.NotaryException: Unable to notarise transactionBEDE8C3F8F2D7A646A9F7D1948DAF77CDAFC37F3B086E09FC766F0D412F02690: One or more input states have been used in another transaction`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create and consume the same Corda state in a single flow.

You need to proceed in two steps:

1. Create a first transaction issuing the new state
2. Create a second transaction consuming the new state

Note that if you create the second transaction and cause a counterparty to call `ResolveTransactionFlow` on it before finalising the first transaction, this will cause a `TransactionResolutionException`, because you don't have the first transaction in your storage to distribute yet. This can occur for example when running `CollectSignaturesFlow`.

Here is an example of building two transactions in the same flow:

```
@InitiatingFlow
@StartableByRPC
class TwoTransactionsFlow(val otherParty: Party) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        val otherPartySessions = listOf(initiateFlow(otherParty))

        val transactionBuilderOne = TransactionBuilder()
        // TODO: Add notary and transaction components.
        val partSignedTransactionOne = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(transactionBuilderOne)
        val fullySignedTransactionOne = subFlow(CollectSignaturesFlow(partSignedTransactionOne, otherPartySessions))
        val notarisedTransactionOne = subFlow(FinalityFlow(fullySignedTransactionOne))

        val transactionOneFirstOutputRef = StateRef(notarisedTransactionOne.id, 0)
        val transactionOneFirstOutput = serviceHub.toStateAndRef<ContractState>(transactionOneFirstOutputRef)

        val transactionBuilderTwo = TransactionBuilder()
                .addInputState(transactionOneFirstOutput)
        // TODO: Add notary and other transaction components.
        val partSignedTransactionTwo = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(transactionBuilderTwo)
        val fullySignedTransactionTwo = subFlow(CollectSignaturesFlow(partSignedTransactionTwo, otherPartySessions))
        subFlow(FinalityFlow(fullySignedTransactionTwo))
    }
}
```

Comment: can you give the sample code how you implemented in same flow?
after executing the finality flow of 1st transaction, do you called 2nd transaction?

Comment: Added an example above :)

Answer (score 1):

Some more points to consider

- In Corda 4, when creating and consuming the state in one flow, the corresponding responder flow should call ReceiveFinalityFlow 2 times(also SignTransactionFlow incase of signers), or else an error will be thrown:-java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: net.corda.core.flows.UnexpectedFlowEndException: Tried to access ended session SessionId(toLong=1984916257986245538) with empty buffer.

Code snippet of Initiator Flow in Java

```java
...

        // Signing the transaction.
        SignedTransaction signedTx = getServiceHub().signInitialTransaction(txBuilder);

        // Creating a session with the other party.
        FlowSession otherPartySession = initiateFlow(otherParty);

        // Obtaining the counterparty's signature.
        SignedTransaction fullySignedTx = subFlow(new CollectSignaturesFlow(
                signedTx, Arrays.asList(otherPartySession), CollectSignaturesFlow.Companion.tracker()));

        //notarized transaction
        SignedTransaction notraizedtransaction = subFlow(new FinalityFlow(fullySignedTx, otherPartySession));

        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // STEP-2:
        //  SINCE NOW WE HAVE A NEW UNCONSUMED RECORD-ANCHOR SO WE MUST MAKE IT CONSUMED ( BY USING THE PREVIOUS OUTPUT AS AN INPUT)
        //
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        StateAndRef oldStateref =  getServiceHub().toStateAndRef(new StateRef(notraizedtransaction.getId(),0));

        Command storeCommand = new Command<>(new AnchorStateContract.Commands.ApproveRecAnchorCmd(), requiredSigners);

        TransactionBuilder txBuilder2 = new TransactionBuilder(notary)
                .addInputState(oldStateref)
                .addCommand(storeCommand);

        txBuilder2.verify(getServiceHub());

        // signing
        SignedTransaction signedTx2 = getServiceHub().signInitialTransaction(txBuilder2);

        // Finalising the transaction.
        SignedTransaction fullySignedTx2 = subFlow(new CollectSignaturesFlow(
                signedTx2, Arrays.asList(otherPartySession), CollectSignaturesFlow.Companion.tracker()));


        //notarized transaction
        return subFlow(new FinalityFlow(fullySignedTx2, otherPartySession));
}
```

Code snippet of ResponderFlow in Java

```java
@InitiatedBy(Initiator.class)
public class Responder extends FlowLogic<SignedTransaction> {
    private FlowSession otherPartySession;

    public Responder(FlowSession otherPartySession) {
        this.otherPartySession = otherPartySession;
    }

    @Suspendable
    @Override
    public SignedTransaction call() throws FlowException
    {

        //this class is used inside call function for the verification purposes before signed by this party
        class SignTxFlow1 extends SignTransactionFlow
        {
            private SignTxFlow1(FlowSession otherPartySession) {
                super(otherPartySession);
            }

            @Override
            protected void checkTransaction(SignedTransaction stx) {
                requireThat(require -> {
                    // Validation Logic
                    return null;
                });
            }
        }

        //this class is used inside call function for the verification purposes before signed by this party
        class SignTxFlow2 extends SignTransactionFlow
        {
            private SignTxFlow2(FlowSession otherPartySession) {
                super(otherPartySession);
            }

            @Override
            protected void checkTransaction(SignedTransaction stx) {
                requireThat(require -> {
                    // Validation Logic
                    return null;
                });
            }
        }
        //Validation, signing and storing of first transaction data
        SecureHash expectedTxId1 = subFlow(new SignTxFlow1(otherPartySession)).getId();
        subFlow(new ReceiveFinalityFlow(otherPartySession, expectedTxId1));

        //Validation, signing and storing of second transaction data
        SecureHash expectedTxId2 = subFlow(new SignTxFlow2(otherPartySession)).getId();
        return subFlow(new ReceiveFinalityFlow(otherPartySession, expectedTxId2));

    }
}
```